# mod_rewrite and if clause

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?name=$1
```

I would like to use something like an if-clause for the rewrite rules.
Only if there is ONE part in the URL after the slash and there are no attributes it should beredirected.

```
website.com/article -> website.com/index.php?name=article
website.com/theme/artcile -> no redirection
website.com/article?any=attribute -> no redirection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# make sure there is no query parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
# make sure there is nothing after a slash if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This will do this rewrites:

1. `website.com/article -> website.com/index.php?name=article`
2. `website.com/article/ -> website.com/index.php?name=article`

This will NOT affect any of these URLs:

1. `website.com/theme/artcile`
2. `website.com/article?any=attribute`